# Very simple query with implode gives implode: invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, mysql, implode, invalid-argument

It's friday, so I am obviously not seeing things strait so I thought to ask here.

I want to get a list of names from the database using:

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT Names FROM Content ORDER BY Names");
```

This should give `JimMikePeter` (at least it does in PHP MyAdmin)

This is not very readable so I thought, lets implode:

```
$line = implode( ", ", $test);
echo $line;
```

This should give: `Jim, Mike, Peter` but it doesn't, it gives: Warning: `implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed`

Also I want the result like this: `"Jim", "Mike", "Peter"` (with quotes)

Any thoughts?

Comment: [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) accepts an array as it's 2nd parameter, you're currently passing the return value from `mysql_query` which isn't an array.

Comment: mysql_query returns a resource, not a string. According to php.net "The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the array using mysql_fetch_array. Using a query as a parameter in implode() will give you an error

Comment: Ahh ofcourse added this: `while ( $a = mysql_fetch_array($test) ) {

     echo '"'.$a['Names'].'"';

}` so how to add the implode?

Comment: Even better how to put this outcome in a new value (I want to re-use this string in $newarray)

Comment: If you want to produce "Jim", "Mike", "Peter", it'll take some more lines of codes:
    while($a = mysql_fetch_array($test)) { $newstring .= '"'.$a['Names'].'", ';}
But now there's an extra comma and space at the end, so you need to remove them after the loop by using rtrim($newstring, ", ")

Answer (score 0):

You should know that mysql_query returns a resource documented in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php) you nead to fetch the data with a fetch function like [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Came up with this, but it's faulty: `while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
echo implode(", ",$arr);
}`